# jersey-all (v.2.22.2) make unresolved package in system console - AEM 6.2

Tags: java, maven, jersey, osgi, aem

I'm trying to connect to third party API service and thought to use jersey-all libraries for that. But after install it from maven and deployed in to the AEM 6.2 server. 
But the project bundle wasn't in 'ACTIVE' status, it was "INSTALLED" due to the following errors.

[image: Unresolved packages in the system/console/bundle section]

Maven dependancy

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.eclipsesource.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The scope specified for this dependency is `provided`. This means that Maven will download these artifacts in order to build your project but will not embed them inside the resulting OSGi bundle.

They're expected to be provided by the OSGi runtime and the packages you can see highlighted in red need to be exported by another bundle (down to the version limitations specified).

You can use the dependency finder in the OSGi console to see if anything exports the packages.

Go to `/system/console/depfinder` and search for the packages.

They're probably exported in a different version than expected or not exported at all.

Installing a bundle exporting the right versions of these packages should allow your bundle to start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I run again after removing "provided" and now it gives me only one unresolved error. 'javax.annotation,version=[1.2,2) -- Cannot be resolved' . How can i use /system/console/definder to find  the package. Do i require to find 'javax.annotation' package ?

Comment: @Harsha Simply removing the explicit `provided` scope makes Maven use the default `compile` scope. You're now embedding the Jersey jars in your own OSGi bundle. Now, I'm speculating as I haven't tried this myself but you're using the `jersey-all` artefact from `com.eclipsesource.jaxrs`, which is the OSGi version of Jersey probably expecting its dependencies to be provided by the OSGi environment. If you want to embed Jars in your bundle, try using the non-OSGi version. But I'd rather deploy the Jersey bundle on its own using the OSGi installer and make sure all dependencies are also available.

Comment: It also may be the case that there is some conflict between the `javax.annotation` version used by Jersey and the one exported by Sling Models. The dependency finder should show you all bundles exporting that package.